# Nuxt routing - dash/hyphen in route and subroute for a dynamic route?

Tags: routes, nuxt.js

I have two questions about Nuxt routing which are not clear to me even after studying the documentation.

**Is there a way how to create routes with a dash/hyphen?**
Something like `user/my-profile`?

I didn't found any info about that.

**And is it possible to create a subroute for a dynamic route?**
I have:
`pages/detail/_id.vue`, which is creating `detail/:id` rotue.
But I need also `detail/:id/something` so I tried this structure:

- `pages/detail/_id.vue`
- `pages/detail/_id/something.vue`

But both are loading `detail/:id`.

Thanks

Comment: It will use a hyphen by default, when you will have your dynamic data. How did you try to reach `something`? Didn't you mean `_something` here? Because `detail/123/something` should work here.

Comment: No, I meant `something.vue`, not a dynamic parameter

Comment: Can you please be more precise on what is not working and provide an example on the URL you're trying to reach?